# ESLINT: Parsing error: Unexpected token in package.json

Tags: json, atom-editor, eslint

```
{
  "name": "react-redux-starter-kit",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This would be the starter kit for react projects.",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "rm -rf build/ && rm -rf dist/ && webpack && webpack-dev-server --progress --colors",
    "build": "rm -rf build/ && rm -rf dist/ && NODE_ENV=production webpack --config ./webpack.production.config.babel.js --progress"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://rahulshettyprdxn@bitbucket.org/rahulshettyprdxn/react-devops.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "webpack",
    "react-native"
  ],
  "author": "Rahul Shetty",
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": "https://bitbucket.org/rahulshettyprdxn/react-devops#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.3",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015-without-strict": "0.0.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "eslint": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^4.1.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.9.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^1.6.3",
    "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
    "react-css-modules": "^3.7.5",
    "react-transform-hmr": "^1.0.2",
    "sass-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.14",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.28.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7"
  }
}
```

Below is the error that I am receiving:
**Parsing error: Unexpected token at line 2 col 8** in Atom editor.

Note that I'm currently getting this error on Windows 10.

ESLint Version:
**"eslint": "^2.2.0",

"eslint-plugin-react": "^4.1.0"**

I have installed **linter-eslint** in my Atom editor and **Global npm ESLint setting** is off.

I am quite confused as the error message is not that descriptive. This in no way is hampering my project but I am quite inquisitive as to why I am getting this error in my editor.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

ESLint is for validating JavaScript, not JSON.

From [the website](http://eslint.org/):

> ESLint
>
> The pluggable linting utility for **JavaScript** and **JSX**

[emphasis mine]

(You can try your code on the online demo [here](http://eslint.org/demo/), and you get the same error)

If you want to use ESLint on a JSON file, you could use a package like [eslint-plugin-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-json).

Comment: Thanks. The issue got resolved. I changed extension to JSON and added the package you suggested.

Answer (score 3):

In .elintrc.json:

```
{
  "overrides" [
    {
      "files": "*.json",
      "parser": "jsonc-eslint-parser",
      "rules": {}
    }
]
```